# How to interpret "ne plus vous lâcher" in these instances?

Tags: sens, usage

> Il y a des films qui vous prennent à la gorge dès le début et qui ne vous **lâchent** plus, celui-ci en est une puissante représentation.
>
> Le genre de problèmes qui ne vous **lâchent** plus.

I wonder if the meaning of "lâcher" in these instances is closest to "quelque chose ne vous sort pas de la tête"? Or is it more like "quelque chose n'arrête pas de vous affecter mentalement"?

Comment: I don't really see a different between the two options you gave. "*Il te lâche plus*" means "it won't go away".

Comment: "Ils ne vous lâchent plus" can also be translated by "they won't relax their grip on you" (even "on your throat" in the first sentence).

Answer (score 2):

The second, as teleporting goat notes, just means "it won't go away". The first case is a perfectly comprehensible extension of the metaphorical throat-grabbing in the same sentence.

Answer (score 1):

*Lâcher*, c'est cesser de tenir, de s'attacher. 
Donc quelque chose qui ne vous lâche plus, c'est quelque chose qui sera toujours attaché à vous, qui ne cessera pas de vous tenir, par exemple par la gorge, comme dans votre premier exemple.

Il est difficile de faire la différence entre 
 "quelque chose ne vous sort pas de la tête" et "quelque chose n'arrête pas de vous affecter mentalement" sans plus de contexte.
Par exemple :

> Depuis que j'ai découvert la conjecture de Syracuse,
>   ce problème ne me lâche plus. (= je n'arrête pas d'y penser)
>
> Depuis que j'ai commencé ma dépression,
>   ce problème ne me lâche plus. (= Ca n'arrête pas de m'affecter.)